# Problems with node.js crypto module

Tags: node.js, cryptography, node-crypto

I am trying to create an HMAC for use in authentication with an API.

However, I'm running into some issues with the standard node crypto.

Looking at this [example](https://www.quadrigacx.com/api_info) under the Authentication section:

```
HMAC_SHA256 ( 13916834993JJHlXeDcFM , 230664ae53cbe5a07c6c389910540729 )
```

Hashing these two values should give me a return value of: `cdbf5cc64c70e1485fcf976cdf367960c2b28cfc28080973ce677cebb6db9681`

However, when I use the crypto library I can't seem to replicate this:

```
crypto.createHash('sha256').update('13916834993JJHlXeDcFM').update('230664ae53cbe5a07c6c389910540729').digest("hex")
```

returns

```
798134a33b4f8af61c85c07b692f907607b03a7b7298faff1f05ec6712006f9c
```

and

```
crypto.createHmac("sha256", '13916834993JJHlXeDcFM').update('230664ae53cbe5a07c6c389910540729').digest('hex');
```

returns

```
3a67e4899e1eae579b3191fdde04a19086cf50f71ee497274e23e413b52a0d00
```

Furthermore, the fact that these are both different is an issue as well. For some reason the createHmac(algorithm, key) method is not working for me.

```
crypto.createHmac("sha256", '13916834993JJHlXeDcFM').digest('hex');
```

Should return

```
1edcb16556338085d86656163314ded51d90f297d9c1a67d87d5b00b9fc44eb5
```

But returns instead:

```
01440fc92c9f2e4923b98cbe0202359b6d2a88ec8b5d54d1690718112f671084
```

I'm trying to debug an error I am receiving in authentication with using a library related to the API listed above, but seem to have run into a handful of errors with the crypto library that is preventing me from getting much useful investigation done.

Comment: try swapping key and data in `createHmac`

Comment: Tried that and just received an error. It seems to me that createHash and createHmac actually create different objects, I can't seem to find something in the documentation though that explains what the difference is between a created hash and a create hmac if they both receive the same parameters for algorithm and key.

Comment: I don't know much about hashing, but swapping key & data in createHmac returned the expected output.

Comment: Wasn't able to get that, could you post the code?

Comment: mrmayfield: HMAC uses the underlying hash function in a special way. You can't just use the normal hashfunction if an HMAC is required. @hassansin I can confirm that swapping key and data produces the expected string. You can post the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Artjom. Any idea where I could read up further on HMAC and the 'special' way it uses the underlying hash function? I'll poke around on the net but on first glance it doesn't seem like it's mentioned anywhere in the Express documentation.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the API example, `MD5 ( secret )` is the key and `nonce + client + key` is your data. So the correct syntax is:

```
crypto.createHmac("sha256", '230664ae53cbe5a07c6c389910540729').update('13916834993JJHlXeDcFM').digest('hex');
```

which outputs:

```
cdbf5cc64c70e1485fcf976cdf367960c2b28cfc28080973ce677cebb6db9681
```

Comment: Right on, thank you. The problem that gave way to this question was a fundamental misunderstanding in the difference between createHash and createHmac, which I thought were different syntax to the same functionality. I'll definitely read more up on, thanks for the answer.